# Condensing, restructuring and adding subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been scratching my head and failing miserably at coming up with a solution to my array structuring issue. I'm not sure exactly what part would be better to try and fix, the data being returned from SQL or the PHP array after the fact.

My SQL data is returned like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $colData[$i] = array(
                    'name' => $row['FULLNAME'],
                    'invoice' => $row['CUST_InvoiceNumber_020911544'],
                    array(
                        'service' => $row['CUST_Service_052400634'],
                        'date' => date_normalizer($row['CUST_ServiceDate_064616924']),
                        'service_amount' =>  $row['CUST_ServiceAmount_054855553'],
                    ),
                    'do_all_for' => $row['CUST_DoAllFor_021206685'],
                    'memo' => $row['CUST_Memo_021614200'],
                    'paymenttype' => $row['CUST_PAYMENTTYPE_123838203'],
                    'deposit' => $row['CUST_DEPOSIT_124139703'],
                    'datepaid' => date_normalizer($row['CUST_DATEPAID_124941578']),
                );
            $i++;
        }
```

And the resultant array has this structure:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'ABRAHAM PRETORIS',
    'invoice' => '63954',
    0 => 
    array (
      'service' => 'Tree Work',
      'date' => '2015-01-22',
      'service_amount' => '1305.00',
    ),
    'do_all_for' => '4924.68',
    'memo' => 'CHECK #947 $2400',
    'paymenttype' => 'VISA',
    'deposit' => '4429.48',
    'datepaid' => '2015-02-09',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'ABRAHAM PRETORIS',
    'invoice' => '63954',
    0 => 
    array (
      'service' => 'DRF',
      'date' => '2015-01-22',
      'service_amount' => '740.00',
    ),
    'do_all_for' => '4924.68',
    'memo' => 'CHECK #947 $2400',
    'paymenttype' => 'VISA',
    'deposit' => '4429.48',
    'datepaid' => '2015-02-09',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'ABRAHAM PRETORIS',
    'invoice' => '63954',
    0 => 
    array (
      'service' => 'Stumps',
      'date' => '2015-01-26',
      'service_amount' => '360.00',
    ),
    'do_all_for' => '4924.68',
    'memo' => 'CHECK #947 $2400',
    'paymenttype' => 'VISA',
    'deposit' => '4429.48',
    'datepaid' => '2015-02-09',
  ),
```

Notice that I'm getting a new subarray for the same person because the sub-subarray (service, date & service_amount) has multiple values.
What I'm trying to accomplish is condensing the array so that I only have one array for "ABRAHAM PRETORIS" etc, but all of the different services listed as a sub array. I would like it to look like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'ABRAHAM PRETORIS',
    'invoice' => '63954',
    0 => 
    array (
      'service' => 'Tree Work',
      'date' => '2015-01-22',
      'service_amount' => '1305.00',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'service' => 'DRF',
      'date' => '2015-01-22',
      'service_amount' => '740.00',
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
      'service' => 'STUMPS',
      'date' => '2015-01-26',
      'service_amount' => '360.00',
    ),
    'do_all_for' => '4924.68',
    'memo' => 'CHECK #947 $2400',
    'paymenttype' => 'VISA',
    'deposit' => '4429.48',
    'datepaid' => '2015-02-09',
  ),
```

I've looked at tons of examples of nested foreach statements and php array functions but I just can't wrap my head around how to loop through and add the additional services to the array then proceed when it's a row with a different name and/or invoice number.
Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your SQL query has an `order by name, invoice`. That will ensure all the records you want to group are sequential.

Then you have to create a loop with some additional inner logic:

```
// Creates an array to hold the final array.
$result = array();
// This var will keep track of name changes.
$current_name = '';
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) 
{
  // Let's check if the name changed. This will be true for the first
  // time the loop runs.
  if($current_name != $row['FULLNAME'])
  {
    // If we are beginning, the if below will not run. But in subsequent 
    // records, it will add the acumulated array to the main result.
    if($current_name != '') $result[] = $temp;
    // The temp array will be populated with all data that DOES NOT change 
    // for the current name.
    $temp = array('name' => $row['FULLNAME'],
                  'invoice' => $row['CUST_InvoiceNumber_020911544'],
                  'do_all_for' => $row['CUST_DoAllFor_021206685'],
                  'memo' => $row['CUST_Memo_021614200'],
                  'paymenttype' => $row['CUST_PAYMENTTYPE_123838203'],
                  'deposit' => $row['CUST_DEPOSIT_124139703'],
                  'datepaid' => date_normalizer($row['CUST_DATEPAID_124941578']),
                 );
    // Update the current name.
    $current_name = $row['FULLNAME'];
  }
  // The part that runs only on name changes has finished. From now on, we
  // will take care of data which will be accumulated 
  // in a sub-array (until name changes and the block above resets it).
  $temp['sub-array'][] = 
      array('service' => $row['CUST_Service_052400634'],
              'date' => date_normalizer($row['CUST_ServiceDate_064616924']),
              'service_amount' => $row['CUST_ServiceAmount_054855553']);
}
// After the loop, the last temp array needs to be added too.
$result[] = $temp;
```

This is the general concept: you will create a temporary array to hold the current name, inside which you will acummulate other data. Once the name changes, the acummulated data will be dumped to the main result, the temp array is reset, and a new acummulation begins.

I can't test the code right now, so it probably needs some fixes, but this approach works really well, and my point here is to show you the concept, so you can adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough Marcovecchio! That makes complete sense.. Now I can finally get this report wrapped up.. lol

Comment: @MikeThiel: I'm glad it helped you! By the way, I just added a missing line, just before the if closing brace: `$current_name = $row['FULLNAME'];`.

Comment: The subarray info is being added successfully to the main array now.. however, it's doing it one at a time and creating a new main array for each addition. I'm working out a solution which I don't think will be difficult. You definitely put me on the right track!!

Comment: thanks again for all the help. My apologies, I accidentally put the $result[] = $temp before the end of the while loop instead of after it. Thanks again!

Comment: The last `$result[] = $temp` will add the last name to the `$results` array. If you don't add it, you will loose the last name. To check that, take a look at your SQL query, and compare it to the `$result` array. The last name will be missing!

Comment: Yes sir, that is indeed the case! I should have tested before writing. Thank you for your patience and swift help!